VS Code displays two activated venvs
Today VS Code got updated to the last version (1.89, april 2024). After this update, whenever I open a terminal (I use Git Bash) there's an active Python venv that I can´t deactivate. I move to the venv's directory (to set an example, /c/Users/my.name/my_project, and inside this folder there's my Python scripts and my venv, let's say it's called venv_project. So, to try and deactivate, I run the deactivate command, but it returns the next message: DeprecationWarning: 'source deactivate' is deprecated. Use 'conda deactivate'., as if it didn't detect the venv (I'm not using conda, by the way), but when I run pip list, I get a list of every library I have installed in it.
So far, I have tried this:

Close the shell, close VS Code and restart my machine. I still get the same activated venv.
Open a Git Bash on its own (not in VS Code), where, by the way, I don't see this activated venv. I open the directory, activate and deactivate the venv, close everything and restart my machine again, still the same.
An extremely weird thing happened when I tried to activate the same venv: it actually did it, and showed the same venv's name between parentheses twice! So for instance, I run source venv_project/Scripts/activate, and on the next line, the terminal shows this: (venv_project) (venv_project) my.name@CPM00001234 MINGW64 c/Users/my.name/my_project (please keep in mind that these paths are just generic examples).
I opened a new Git Bash, pointing at a different folder with a different venv (on VS Code, I clicked on Terminal > New terminal and then I picked the other directory, let's say /c/Users/my.name/another_project, and surprise! The venv on that folder was activated as well (so I see this: (venv_anotherproject) my.name@CPM00001234 MINGW64 c/Users/my.name/another_project, and I have the exact same issues as with the first one.

I must clarify that I always try to deactivate my venvs whenever they're not in use, but even if I ever forgot to do that, when I closed VS Code and opened it again, or just killed the Bash and opened a new one, the venv wasn't active anymore.

Another thing I tried is checking the directories on my path, by running echo $PATH. I only did this because that's what Copilot recommended; I don't fully understand what this path is, all I know is that I was supposed to check if my venv's directory was on the list, and it was. I was also supposed to delete this directory from the path, by opening my bash profile (/c/Users/my.name in this case) and running nano ~/.bashrc or .bash_profile or whatever the name of the file was, but... there is not such file in my profile, so when I run the nano command, it just returns an empty screen, there's no directories in there.
The most baffling thing so far: I decided to delete my venv, but... the venv's name still shows between parentheses! I ran pip list and the libraries are gone, but the name is still there, even after I close VS code, reboot my machine and open VS Code again.

These are basically the steps I've taken to try and solve my problem. The thing is that this just started to be an issue with this new VS Code version so, as an alternative, is there a way to reset VS Code to the prior version?
PS: one thing I just discovered is that this problem doesn't show on windows shells, like cdm or powershell, but it does show on Cygwin, another shell I have installed.
PS2: I've found a way to avoid this behaviour, I had an opened workspace with several project folders I'm working on. Somehow, by deleting this workspace and creating a new workspace, this venv activation stopped. I assume there must be something new about workspace configuration that automatically activates venvs in this last VS Code update, but it's still really strange that I can't deactivate them myself. I would still like to understand why this is happening, to avoid future problems.

I haven't dealt with this myself, but it sounds like it could maybe be a case of environment duplication -- interference with conda init #22233. There's a maintainer comment about something to do with running conda config --set auto_activate_base False and restarting the shell to fix it (though it apparently doesn't impact behaviour?), and a future improvement to the UI to only show one of them: Adopt to using VS Code API to access terminal output #22128, and other changes related to terminal environment activation- Rollout for terminal env var activation #20950.
